# Number of ways for 2 objects to not be beside each other in a line

Tags: combinatorics

My combinatorics is a bit rusty, if someone could remind me;

Suppose I have A,B,C,D,E, and I'm trying to count the number of ways to put them in a row, however.... where A and B cannot be beside each other.

Would this be $(\binom21\cdot3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1)$

Best wishes!

Comment: Hint: How many arrangements are there in total? How many arrangements are there where A and B are beside each other?

Comment: The OP's proposed answer counts the number of ways A or B can be put at the *head* of the line and one of the other three put second.  There are additional ways to keep A and B separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3!=6$ ways to arrange C, D, and E. Once you’ve arranged them, you must pick $2$ of the $4$ slots defined by them into which to insert A and B. (These is one slot to the left of all of them and one to the right of all of them, and there are $2$ between adjacent letters.) There are $\binom42=6$ ways to do that. Finally, you have to decide which of A and B goes in the leftmost of the $2$ slots that you chose, and you can do that in $2$ ways. The total number of possibilities is therefore

$$3!\cdot\binom42\cdot2=6\cdot6\cdot2=72\;.$$

Thus, you’re short by a factor of $2$.

Comment: As the other comments mentioned, I had a feeling I had ignored the possibility of it placed in the center. Thanks for the clear expression!

Comment: @sahimat: You’re welcome!